# VLC freezes in fullscreen

Tags: linux-mint, vlc-media-player, codec, avi

I am running VLC media player 2.0.6 Twoflower under Linux Mint 17.

I do not have a dedicated graphics card so the display output is set to X11.

With certain .avi files (not all of them) the video plays fine until I switch to full screen mode.  After which, the video freezes but the sound continues.  I am unable to kill the VLC process with the command:

`sudo killall vlc`

But I can close the window and kill the process with webmin instead.

No clues to the bug when I view the VLC error logs.

When I play the same video in MPlayer, everything is sluggish and the lips are not synced.  However, the video plays perfectly in VLC for Windows...  The same video used to play perfectly on my Linux box too!

This problem had never happened before...  Could the installation of sopcast corrupt some codec files?  Or maybe plexmediaserver messed it up somehow?  Or was it an automatic update of some kind?

Help would be appreciated.